# Getting rid of a Firebug pop up menu?

Tags: firefox, firebug

When I click on DOM elements of a page, I get the following Firebug popup showing:

[image: firebug annoyance]

It's really annoying. How do I disable that?

Comment: Are you doing anything before it pops up?

Comment: I'm just clicking on the dom elements.

Answer (score 10):

In Firebug, on the HTML tab, click the small arrow to bring up the menu.  The last item in that menu is "Show Quick Info Box".  Uncheck this option and you should stop getting that menu.

[image: Screenshot of option]

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. On the popup window, click on "Tools" and uncheck the first option - Guess it is "always open" and you are done.

Comment: I know this is a necropost, but the popup may be malware, so better not to click on anything in the popup.